# how to parse html by using class name in lxml.etree python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, lxml

```
req = requests.get(url)
tree = etree.HTML(req.text)
```

now instead of using xpath `tree.xpath(...)` I would like to know if we can search by class name of id as we do in beautifulSoup 
`soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'myclass'})`  I'm looking for something similar in lxml.

Comment: Why would you not use XPath?  That would seem to do exactly what you want.   https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support

Answer (score 2):

The far more concise way to do that in `bs4` is to use a css selector:

```
soup.select('div.myclass') #  == soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'myclass'})
```

`lxml` provides `cssselect` as a module (which actually [compiles XPath expressions](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html)) and as a convenience method on `Element` objects.

```
import lxml.html

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(req.text)
for div in tree.cssselect('div.myclass'):
    #stuff
```

Or optionally you can pre-compile the expression and apply that to your `Element`:

```
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
selector = CSSSelector('div.myclass')

selection = selector(tree)
```

Answer (score 1):

You say that you don't want to use xpath but don't explain why. If the goal is to search for a tag with a given class, you can do that easily with xpath.

For example, to find a div with the class "foo" you could do something like this:

```
tree.find("//div[@class='foo']")
```